# Blazor Server App Published to IIS getting Your Connection is not private

Tags: iis, blazor

I am working on a blazor server side app, to publish as an intranet site.  Once it has been published and access the site I am getting a your connection isn't private.  How do I go about getting this fixed.

Comment: Use a valid server certificate other than the default self-signed one.

Comment: How do I go about doing that? I am new to the web side of development.

Comment: Then ask a search engine. Usually commercial sites buy their certificates from CAs such as https://www.verisign.com/en_US/website-presence/online/ssl-certificates/index.xhtml. There are also free alternatives.

Comment: If you just need to use certificate for intranet, visual studio makecert tool could help .https://blog.jayway.com/2014/09/03/creating-self-signed-certificates-with-makecert-exe-for-development/